# How can I use 'Jenkins own user database' to login while the `OpenID SSO` is on?

Tags: jenkins

My jenkins have configured to use `OpenID SSO` to login.
My question is how to use a **Jenkins normal user** to login without changing the `Security Realm` from `OpenID SSO` to `Jenkins’ own user database`.

By saying **Jenkins normal user**, I mean those who signs up from the jenkins signup page: http://your_jenkins_url/signup

[image: jenkins signup page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't easily possible.

As mentioned in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21157396/234938), the easiest solution would be to  add this extra user to your SSO system.

Alternatively, as the other non-accepted answer there mentions, along with [this mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/d52iTQyD-XM), you could look into setting up PAM authentication, as that would let you delegate to multiple authentication schemes.